# Stop hover event on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I've got a menu overlaying an animated div. The div animates opacity on hover. The problem is, with the menu z-indexed over the div, the li's are interrupting the div hover, causing a mouseleave event and triggering the div to opacity:1. I've coded an interrupt for the menu li's as below, but with no effect.

```
var ovver=false;
$("#nav li").hover(function () {
     ovver=true;
}, function () {
     ovver=false;
});
$('#hero div').hover(function() {
    if (!ovver) {
        $('#hero div').stop().animate({'opacity':0},{duration:650, easing:'easeInOutSine'});
    }
}, function() {
    if (!ovver) {
        $('#hero div').stop().animate({'opacity':1},{duration:650, easing:'easeInOutSine'});
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why the variable isn't working, but hovering over the li's still triggers the opacity:1 animation. What am I doing wrong??!!!

Edit: SOLVED. For some reason, the second hover event on #hero div was consistently executing before the first hover event. I don't know why. I added a setTimeout to the second hover event before the if statement, and it worked like a charm.

If anyone can suggest why the second hover event persists in triggering first, regardless of DOM structure, Jquery order or anything else I could think of, I'd be interested. Otherwise, I'm going to file this under "WTF", and keep it in mind for next time.

Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that CSS "!important" will actually over-write JQuery stuff, even for inline additions.

```
<style type='text/css'>
#hero div:hover{
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

**In response to the first comment by Sean Murphy**

Perhaps obscure jQuery and CSS wizardry could do the trick?

```
$('#hero div').hover(function(){
    $('#nav li').css("cssText","opacity: 0; !important;");
});
```

If the `cssText` looks a little funky to you, [read this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066). Also, I'm not 100% sure this will work.

Comment: Oops, not quite the problem: the animation plays just fine; unfortunately, it plays even when the menu buttons are moused over. That's what I'm trying to solve: why the above won't keep the hover animation from playing when the li's are moused over. I thought I'd left a pointer-events:none in the CSS, but that wasn't the case. Sorry, man, but nice try!

Comment: Updated my answer if you're still interested

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about cssText... wasn't aware of that one. Unfortuately, didn't work either. I'm thinking it's because of the double event placed on the hover eventHandler, though I've seen jsFiddles online that seem to not have this problem. I'm currently experimenting with another route involving stopImmediatePropogation. Will let you know.